# How to extract data from text file in python after a certain string in the text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose there is a file which has `'qasd erty123'` in it. I want to extract `123` in `'erty123'` from the file. The length of `123` is in a input variable, therefore, unknown to me. I have tried

```
index=string.find('erty')+len('erty')       
print('index')      
Output:9
```

How to print after that?

Comment: first load file to memory (`open()`, `read()`) and then you have string and you can use `find("erty")` and other functions which work with string. Or you can split text into words and search in list. Or use module `re` to use `regex`.

Comment: if you use find() then you get index and you can use `slicing` ( `[start:stop]`)  to do `you_string[index:index+some_value]` or `you_string[index+len("erty"):index+len("erty")+some_value]` and display part of this string. If you split into words and use `index()` to find word "erty" then you can get next word from list `your_list[index_of_erty+1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load file to memory and then you can search in string using `find()`

It display everything after `erty`

```
text = "qasd erty123"

index = text.find('erty')

index = index + len('erty')

print(text[index:])
```

If text is longer then it may need more work to get interested part.

It looks for `'erty'` and next it looks for space after `'erty'` - this is why I use `start` in `find()`. Without `start` it will find space before `'erty'`

```
text = "qasd erty123 hello"

index = text.find('erty')

start = index + len('erty')
end = text.find(' ', start)

print(text[start:end])
```

More complex text may need to use `regex`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me solve my problem.